# Ado.net Entity Data model - Crud issues

Tags: entity-framework, crud

Im new to ADO.net Entity Data Model.

I need some advice as I'm getting confused trailing round the web looking for answers. So I have an existing MS SQL DB with 2.5m+ records. The standard SQL data connection was is becoming slow so i have look into EF.

The database consists of Table/ View & Stored procedures. Using a standard SQL connection i have been using Views to display data from 3 or more tables (the views do contain joins) and Stored Procedures to do CRUD operations.

So im looking for advice:-

Can i use the existing DB in it current form. I have tried this approach and have had some success with a single table with crud fully working.

Steps to do the above was new project - then add new ado.net entity data model - select 1 table. - then rebuld project - then add EntityServerModeDataSource to the page - select ID and the tablename - enable delete & update - then add a aspxgridview to the page and bind the Data source. Modify the code behind as per below Modift the Model mappings for to include the SQL stored procedures and run and test the project.

I then tried to use a view and 2 stored procedures (Update, Delete). The delete works fine but the Update throws and error which reads - 
System.ArgumentException: 'The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Parameter name: keyValues'

Here is my code behind for deleting:-

```
protected void EntityServerModeDataSource1_Deleting(object sender, 
DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceEditEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = (int)e.Keys[ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName];


        using (overstayEntities1 context = new overstayEntities1())
        {
            var item = context.zactests.Find(ID);
            if (item != null)
            {
                context.zactests.Remove(item);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

---

and here is my code behind for updating:-

```
protected void EntityServerModeDataSource1_Updating1(object sender, 
DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceEditEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = (int)e.Keys[ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName];
        using (overstayEntities1 context = new overstayEntities1())
        {
            var item = context.zactests.Find(ID);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.VRMEditable = (string)e.Values["VRMeditable"];

                context.SaveChanges();
```

If i can get of this issue then that great. Otherwise i will need so clear steps to take.

So as far as display & deleting the data it work very quickly im just hope its a syntax issue on the updating. I am using DEVExpress aspxgridview to display the data but when i asked them the question they point me in this direction as its more of a EF issue

Any Help would be appreciated - Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure that performance problem is a good motivation to move from raw SQL to EF. If your SQL is slow try to understand why first. EF will not (directly) be the solution. Redesign of DB and/or index creation should be a first step.

Comment: Hi - Sql is not slow just the ASP.net pages fetching the records with EF the speed is no longer an issue providing i can get help with the updating issue. SQL views and SP's work fine. In this example there are only 3 tables a primary table and 2 image tables with the PK of the main table. Yes there is no database diagram with the relationships but i have inherited this db and redesign is not on my radar atm